# Streamwriter putting table cells on new row in MS Egde instead of same row

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge, streamwriter

I've got some automated tests in Selenium using .net, and have utilised Streamwriter to copy data from a table in a web application. This works fine in Chrome, in that I've made the Streamwriter copy an entire row from a table and append that to a line in a csv file i.e...

```
DepartmentCodeDepartmentDescriptionTotalSpendTotalValue(%)SubjectivesLines
1Dep-100054Department-10005415282.403.1033861884
2Dep-100038Department-10003814282.292.9033962096
```

However in Edge the same code puts each cell on a new line...

```
DepartmentCode
DepartmentDescription
TotalSpend
TotalValue(%)
Suppliers
Transactions
Directorates
CostCentres
Subjectives
Lines
1
Dep-100054
Department-100054
15282.40
3.10
3
3
8
6
18
84
2
Dep-100038
Department-100038
14282.29
2.90
3
3
9
6
20
96
```

The code for the Streamwriter is...

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(actualDataFileLocation, false))
        {
            //Used for loop for number of rows
            for (int i = 1; i <= RowCount + 3; i++)
            {
                if (i == 2) // | i == 3)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                string line = string.Empty;
                string tableData = null;
                string finalXpath = null;

                if (i == 1 || i == 3)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= ColCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == 1)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            finalXpath = FirstPartHeader + i + SecondPartHeader + j + ThirdPartHeader;
                            tableData = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(finalXpath)).Text;
                            tableData = tableData.Replace(",", "");
                            tableData = tableData.Replace(" ", "");
                        }
                        line = line + string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", tableData);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    finalXpath = FirstPart + i + SecondPart;
                    tableData = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(finalXpath)).Text;
                    tableData = tableData.Replace(",", "");
                    tableData = tableData.Replace(" ", "");
                    line = line + string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", tableData);
                }
                sw.WriteLine(line.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: Bit of googling and found that using `tableData = tableData.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');` to remove carriage return works for the header row, but not the other data rows in the second else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit more googling and utilising `Replace("\r", "")` and `Replace("\n", "");` did the trick